# Replacing line content and newline

Tags: regex, perl

If I'd line to replace, for instance:

```
%bozo%

lol
```

With:

```
is_a_clown
lol
```

What sort of approach should I take? I'd expect a regex substitution with `s` would be the way to go, but I'm unsure whether there's a better/doable approach.

Answer (score 3):

> What sort of approach should I take?

The substitution operator `s///`, See [Substitutions with s///](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/lperl/ch09_06.htm)

Perl's substitute operator lets you replace a *Regular Expression* with another string within a target string.

```
my $str = "foo";
$str =~ s/foo/bar/;

# $str is now 'bar'
```

See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (Perl regular expressions) for the various modifiers also.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question itself, "I'd expect a regex substitution with `s` would be the way to go, but I'm unsure whether there's a better/doable approach.". So, how would you go with `s///` about handling this case?

Comment: `$str = "%bozo%\n\nlol"; $str =~ s/%bozo%\n/is_a_clown/; print $str;`